# Cannot install dev dependencies with NPM

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, package-managers

When I run `npm install`, all regular dependencies are installed. However, dev-dependencies aren't. As I understand it, by default, both should be installed. I haven't changed my `NODE_ENV`, and I've never had this issue before. However, it started after this completely wiping computer's drives and freshly installing Windows.

Comment: Are u getting any error?

Comment: Can you report back what value is set in NODE_ENV? If set to **production** then npm won't install modules listed in devDependencies. Also try deleting **package-lock.json** and run `npm i`.